# OpenGL vs Antigrain Geometry?

Tags: opengl

Rebol (600 Ko only) is based on antigrain geometry library which is Opensource
http://www.antigrain.com/

It seems really great, can OpenGL do better ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're not really designed for accomplishing the same things. OpenGL can almost certainly do better at 3D rendering (or at least faster at it), as well as better at having hardware level support. It depends on what you need to accomplish, and where.

Answer (score 1):

Can a software renderer work better/faster than a hardware renderer?...
Unlikely.